# Probability Group Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a simple probability group question:

We have selected a group of people to take a survey. 35% of the group like A, 20% like both A and B, and 25% like neither A nor B.

Given this information, what percentage of the sample likes B?

Comment: OK, this should be as simple as drawing a Venn diagram and performing region chasing.

Comment: 100% - (% that like A) - (% that like neither A nor B) = (% that like only B). Add to that the (% that like A and B) to get the total that likes B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people that like either $A$ or $B$ or both of them are $1$ minus the people that like none of these two. So we have:

$P(A\cup B)=1-0.25=0.75$

And now using the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we have that:

$P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) \Rightarrow 0.75=0.35+P(B)-0.2 \iff P(B)=0.6$

Comment: Thanks Michail!